# Proporção de layout HTML

Tags: html, css, materialize

Estou iniciando um projeto utilizando a biblioteca `materialize css`, não tenho muito conhecimento em `layouts`, estou com dificuldades quanto a proporção dos elementos do `HTML`. No `layout` a seguir, está com a proporção esperada:

[image: Layout]

Porém, ao abrir o site em um `layout` menor (`mobile`), os elementos na tela estão muito pequenos :

[image: Layout mobile]

Gostaria que ao acessar o site através de algum `layout` menor, os campos tomassem uma proporção maior.

Código que tenho até agora :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href="fonts/google.fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/materialize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    </head>
    <body class="yellow darken-2">
        <div class="container login-container">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="col s4 offset-s4 login-form">

                  <div class="row col s2 offset-s2">
                     <img class="img-logo" src="img/logo2.png">
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                      <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
                      <label for="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                      <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
                      <label for="password">Senha</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="button" name="action">Entrar
                            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

custom.css

```
.login-container {
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.img-logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione a tag a seguir no cabeçalho do seu código html para controlar o layout em navegadores de dispositivos móveis.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

[Saiba mais sobre o viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: Muito obrigado @abfurlan, resolveu o meu problema!